# VSCode open terminal with directory does not appear to work

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

Having found the [VSCode command](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39#_open-new-terminals-with-custom-working-directories) `workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd`

```
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+alt+h",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd",
    "args": {
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
}
```

I cannot get it to work.

I have inserted the JSON above into the `~\Code\User\keybindings.json` file, but how do I actually get it to execute?

Answer (score 0):

This works as a keybinding, using the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command):

```
{
  "key": "alt+k",       // whatever you want here
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
        "args": {
          "profileName": "Git Bash",
          "shouldForwardArgs": true,
        }
      }
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "cd '${fileDirname}'\u000D"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

---

What I think should work is this profile in settings.json:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
      "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
      },
      "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
          "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
          "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
      },
      "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"
      },
      "Git Bash at fileDirname": {
        "source": "Git Bash",
        "path": "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe",
        "args": [
          "cd ${fileDirname}"       // variables are supported here according to the docs
        ]
      }
    },
```

and then this associated keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
    "args": {
      "profileName": "Git Bash at fileDirname",
      "shouldForwardArgs": true
    }
  },
```

But it doesn't quite work for me.  It almost works, but it says no such file exists.  I see a couple of issues filed on variable resolution in profiles.